# What is the problem with `PySet_Contains` when calling Py func in C?

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes, pyobject

I write C source code like this, aiming to accelerate the Python code with C, so I include some py object and func in C:

- include header file `Python.h` and dynamic link file `libpython3.8.so`.

```c
// test.h
#include "Python.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// test.c
void main(){
    PyObject *bigrams1 = PySet_New(0);
    
    ret = PySet_Add(bigrams, PyUnicode_FromWideChar(L"nc", 2));
    ret = PySet_Add(bigrams, PyUnicode_FromWideChar(L"ckd", 3));
    ret = PySet_Add(bigrams, PyUnicode_FromWideChar(L"nc.3e", 5));
    // and I check the following if the nc string in in bigrams:
    ret = PySet_Contains(bigram, PyUnicode_FromWideChar(L"nc", 2));

}
```

- In this code I create a Python `set` object and add three string to it, `'nc', 'ckd', 'nc.3e'`. The strings added to the set are random, this is not the key point of the problem.
- and when I check `if 'nc' in bigram`, which correspond to the `PySet_Contains` func, the running code corrupts.

```
./test: line 10: 2976044 Segmentation fault
```

But when I change the `nc` to other strings like anyone else `'ok', 'ckd', 'project'`,
the code was running correctly. Only the `nc` caused the bug.

What is the problem with the code and the strange string `nc`?

### Additional description

- I tried both `Python3.8` and `Python3.11` and the results are the same.
- I tried thousands of other strings like `'中国', 'few', '$$####', '1e32e2'`, all the other strings work well.
- That's the strange string `'nc'`.

Comment: `ret` is not defined. It's `int main()` not `void main()`. How do you compile your program?

Comment: Please remove either the "c" or "c++" tag. Also, provide a [mcve] along with e.g. the compiler commandline and the output it produces.

Comment: The dupe target might not be the best. You don’t initialize the python interpreter, such segfaults will bebte result.

Comment: The reason for the segfault is that you didn't call  ```Py_Initialize();```. Full reference for embedding a python interpreter in a C application here:  https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

Comment: The key point is NOT how to call a Py func in C. the key point IS: the special string `nc` caused the segment fault when calling the PySet_Contains while others like any one else didn't!

Comment: But still thank all you guys for your help!!!